# Wacom: ubuntu does not recognize PAD

Tags: wacom, stylus

In my ubuntu 18.04 I cannot configure my stylus. In the configuration menue it says stylus not found, I should bring it near the tablet (what I indeed do).
When using terminal and typing

```
xsetwacom --list
```

I get

```
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M stylus   id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M eraser   id: 18  type: ERASER
```

and only this!
After plugging in to an other USB, it shows "all" 4 entries, but then, later it only shows these very 2 entries on the same USB!